# can asp.net access flash shared object?

Tags: asp.net, flash, actionscript, object, shared

I'm looking for a direct way for server-side code to access a flash shared object. Obviously you can write some javascript that can read flash shared objects via ExternalInterface. But doing that requires a client code execution, and then a push of the shared object data back to the server-side code. This seems rather complicated.

So is there a way for asp.net, php, or any other server-side script to request the data in a flash shared object?

Hope this question makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash is a client side runtime.

Therefore, you require some client side code execution to get the values out of it.

Javascript is as good an option as you'll get (without having the Flash app phone home itself).